# No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier when using Sendgrid in android

Tags: java, android, sendgrid

Getting the above error when trying to use Sendgrid in my android app

build.gradle

```java
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:4.9.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Getting the error in line 14 from this example: https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/v3-java-code-example

Edit:
I tried adding this to build.gradle but it didn't solve the issue

```
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
```

Adding this results in a bunch of `Duplicate class` errors

```
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
```

Answer (score -1):

Sendgrid's Java library is not tuned to work with Android out-of-the-box unfortunately and encounters issues like you've discovered.

I have created and continue to maintain an Android Sendgrid library that you are welcome to use.

https://github.com/jakebreen/android-sendgrid

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.jakebreen:android-sendgrid:1.3.1'
}
```

Raise an issue on the repository's issue board if you any queries.